# Python Bridge with MITM function

Tags: python, redirect, networking, man-in-the-middle, bridging

I'm currently trying to figure out a way to bridge two physical network interfaces with the option to modify packets however I want in Ubuntu.
I want, that every packet which is redirected is checked for special content by some if's.

Since I cannot find a similar tool I decided to write my own.

Has anyone of you experience with things like that and can give me some hints which librarys I should use to do that in python?

best regards